# PDO OCI8 2.0.0, Error while compiling on centos linux 6.5

Tags: php, linux, oracle, pdo

I am new on Linux. I am compiling PDO oci8 for Oracle on PHP 5.6. And I am using 12.1 instant client for Oracle.

I am following this link to install.

http://shiki.me/blog/installing-pdo_oci-and-oci8-php-extensions-on-centos-6-4-64bit/

But on make command I am facing lots of errors.

```
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-rootra3mow/oci8-2.0.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/var/tmp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootra3mow/oci8-2.0.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootra3mow/oci8-2.0.0/main -I/var/tmp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/oci8/oci8.c -o oci8.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/var/tmp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootra3mow/oci8-2.0.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootra3mow/oci8-2.0.0/main -I/var/tmp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/oci8/oci8.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8.o
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_config.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:35,
                 from /var/tmp/oci8/oci8.c:35:
/usr/include/php/main/../main/php_config.h:1230: error: expected ë=í, ë,í, ë;í, ëasmí or ë__attribute__í before ëHAVE_OCI8_DTRACEí
```

There are some other errors. I will upload if needed.

Please help, Every type of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be an option to just use the binary RPMs provided by your OS?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem would be downloading PDO_OCI from PECL.  This, similar to other DB's PDO drivers, is obsoleted and you must use the PDO_OCI code from a PHP source bundle.

I'd strongly recommend using OCI8 instead of PDO_OCI.  OCI8 has all sorts of things like connection pooling, statement caching etc.